# react hook and useeffect remove my state unexpected result

Tags: reactjs

```js
const [track1, settrack1] = useState('')
    const [track2, settrack2] = useState('')
    const [shownotfound, setshownotfound] = useState(false)
    useEffect(() => {
        socket.on('found', function(data) {
            let ob = JSON.parse(data)
            console.log('found', data)
            settrack1(ob.track1)
            settrack2(ob.track2)
        })
    }, [track1])
    useEffect(() => {
        socket.on('notfound', function(data) {
            settrack1('')
            settrack2('')
            setshownotfound(true)
        })
    }, [track2])
```

This code will listen to event from websocket, if the sock event is `found` do something, if the sock event is `not  found`  do something else.

Problem, when the server emit event `found` only, the code will execute all case.

I got something wrong with the hook here?

Comment: When the `found` event is emitted, you change both `track1` *and* `track2` values. This will trigger both effects, since `track1` is a dependency of first effect, and `track2` is dependency of second effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first `useEffect`, you called `settrack1` and `settrack2`. In this case, `settrack2` will launch the second `useEffect`. The same thing happens on second `useEffect`. That's why the code executes in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you added track2 as a dependency in the second useEffect [track2]. When 'found' launches there is settrack2 that changes track2 and launches the second useEffect.